# Angular 2 cant show marker on google map using socket.io

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services, angular-google-maps

i am new in Angular 2,i am trying to show marker on google map with array **[{id:"1",lat:"",long:""},{id:"2",lat:"",long:""}]**, inside of socket i am  able to get the data in **this.markers** but outside of function i mean on html the data is not showing, the markers variable is out of scope and its showing undefined if i print it outside

code --

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ProjectService } from '../service/project.service';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../service/authenticate.service';
import { ChatService } from './chat.service';
import { AgmCoreModule } from 'angular2-google-maps/core';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
@Component({
    selector: 'car',
    templateUrl: 'car.component.html',
    styles: [` .sebm-google-map-container {
       height: 300px;
     }`]
})
export class carDetails implements OnInit {
    public markers: any[];
    private url = 'http://localhost:2222';
    private socket;
    connection;
    title: string = 'Map';
    lat: number = 22.57305679;
    lng: number = 88.43082201;
    public cabData: any = [];
    constructor(
        private AuthenticationService: AuthenticationService,
        private _elementRef: ElementRef
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.socket = io(this.url);
        this.socket.emit("carArrayPosition", this.cabData);
        this.socket.on('currentCarPositionData', (data) => {
            this.markers = data;
           console.log(this.markers); //printing the data
        }); console.log(this.markers); //not printing data
    }



    logout() {
        this.AuthenticationService.logout();
    }

}
```

Comment: i have put a data receiving interval of 9 sec to resolve this kind of problem .

Comment: Don't put a 9s interval as a workaround. Understand what asynchronism is and how it works. You will get your markers data _when it's ready_, which means inside the callback function. Outside, it's undefined.

Comment: i solved it, was kind of silly mistake as i did't notice the incoming data. it was not asynchronous issue because in case of map asynchronous dsnt mttr, marker can be loaded anytime . my db  data type was string and on map we need float that was the issue ..